# JavaScript adds "\" to a CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to populate index.html with the contents from an array using a loop in JavaScript. However, a CSS class used for picture formatting is getting some weird "" characters around it, so it doesn't reflects on browser (latest version of Firefox).

I'd need to know why this happens, how avoid it, or maybe another way to let this CSS class to apply in the final result.

[image: This is what I get on Firefox debugger]

```js
function popularIndex(){
  $("#mostrarRecetas").html("");
  let listadoRecetas = "";
  for (i = 0; i < recetas.length; i++) {
    let articuloReceta = '<div>';
    articuloReceta += '<div class="recetaFoto">' //here is where I getting the "\recetaFoto\" thing
    articuloReceta += '<img src=/images/' + recetas[i].foto + '></div>';
    articuloReceta += '<div> <h1>' + recetas[i].titulo + '</h1></div>';
    articuloReceta += '<div class="card bg-light"><div class="card-body row"><div class="col-sm-6"><p>' + recetas[i].autor + '</p></div><div class="col-sm-6"><p>' + recetas[i].tiempo + 'minutos</p></div></div></div>'
    articuloReceta += '<div><p>' + recetas[i].metodo + '</p></div>'
    articuloReceta += '<div class="card-body row"><div><p>' + recetas[i].likes + '</p></div><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="material-icons"aria-hidden="true">thumb_up</i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="material-icons"aria-hidden="true">thumb_down</i></button></div><div><p>' + recetas[i].dislikes + '</p></div></div>'    
    articuloReceta += '</div>';
    listadoRecetas += articuloReceta;
  }
  $("#mostrarRecetas").html($("#mostrarRecetas").html() + listadoRecetas);
```

This is the class I'm trying to apply.

```
#recetaFoto {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't "add" it, it's just an escape character

Comment: could you show your css. you wanna apply it to `img` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript didnt add \ to your code its escape special characters, to be able to use `"` inside a string you can use `'words  " words ...'` (as you did) or `"words  \" words ..."` its pretty much the same thing.

You should use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

try this:

```js
$("#mostrarRecetas").html("")
let listadoRecetas = "";
for (i = 0; i < recetas.length; i++) {
  
  let articuloReceta = `<div>
    <div id="recetaFoto">
      <img src="/images/${recetas[i].foto}" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>${recetas[i].titulo}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-light">
      <div class="card-body row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>${recetas[i].autor}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>${recetas[i].tiempo} minutos</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>${recetas[i].metodo}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body row">
      <div>
        <p>${recetas[i].likes}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="search-icon">
            <i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">thumb_up</i>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" id="search-icon">
            <i class="material-icons" aria-hidden="true">thumb_down</i>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>${recetas[i].dislikes}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;

  listadoRecetas += articuloReceta;
}
$("#mostrarRecetas").html($("#mostrarRecetas").html() + listadoRecetas);
```

what you were doing wrong is `'<img src=/images/' + recetas[i].foto + '></div>'` should be `'<img src="/images/' + recetas[i].foto + '"></div>'`

Comment: I like this more than the way I was trying to, but the class is still not being applied to the HTML. Same with the second .card Bootstrap class.

Comment: which class is not applied ?

Comment: `<div class="recetaFoto"> //this one
      <img src="/images/${recetas[i].foto}" />
 </div>`

Comment: Sorry I didnt get what you want, do you want to apply a class to the img tag ? or change the class of the div tag ?

Comment: I want to apply that class to the img tag. I first tried putting it inside the img but didn't worked either.

Comment: insead of this `<div class="recetaFoto"><img src="/images/${recetas[i].foto}" /></div>` use this `<div><img class="recetaFoto" src="/images/${recetas[i].foto}" /> </div>`

Comment: Just did it, it's still not working.

I'm just trying to give them some format.

`#recetaFoto {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit:cover;
}`

Comment: OMG i just saw it

Comment: its an id not a class

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to invoke #recetaFoto using class="recetaFoto".

"#" is for IDs, and it used to be an ID until I chose to turn it into a class. Unfortunately I didn't changed it to .recetafoto in the css after I did that on the script.

All these wasted hours...